# How to make the ball push the square?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a SKSpriteNode and a SKShapeNode. I'd like the SKShapeNode to push the SKSpriteNode like it has a larger mass than the SKSpriteNode. However, the opposite seems to be happening even though I've explicitly set the mass of the SKShapeNode to be larger. Here are my two nodes:

```
    - (void)newBallNode {
// Create the sprite.
SKShapeNode *shape = [[SKShapeNode alloc]init];
//// Color Declarations
UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1 green: 0.114 blue: 0.114 alpha: 1];

//// Oval Drawing
UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 17, 18)];
[color setFill];
[ovalPath fill];
const CGAffineTransform *transform = NULL;

shape.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20),transform);

shape.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
shape.zPosition = 10;
shape.strokeColor = shape.fillColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0
                                                                 green:128.0/255.0
                                                                  blue:255.0/255.0
                                                                 alpha:1.0];

// Assign a random angle to the ball's velocity.
const CGFloat ballSpeed = 200;
const CGFloat angle = DegreesToRadians(RandomFloat() * 360);
const CGVector velocity = CGVectorMake(cos(angle)*ballSpeed, sin(angle)*ballSpeed);

// Create a circular physics body. It collides with the borders and
// with other balls. It is slightly smaller than the sprite.
SKPhysicsBody *body = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:30];
body.dynamic = YES;
body.velocity = velocity;
body.friction = 0.0;
body.linearDamping = 0.0;
body.angularDamping = 0.0;
body.restitution = 0.0;
body.mass = 10;
body.categoryBitMask = ballCategory;
body.collisionBitMask = goalCategory | bumperCategory | swipeShapeCategory;
body.contactTestBitMask = 0x0;
shape.physicsBody = body;
[_worldLayer addChild:shape];
   }

-(void)addNewSwipeShape
   {

uint32_t colorCategoryArray[4] = {blueColorCategory, redColorCategory, greenColorCategory, yellowColorCategory};
//NSArray *colorArray = @[[SKColor blueColor], [SKColor redColor], [SKColor greenColor], [SKColor yellowColor]];
int r = self.randomInt;
_swipeShape = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] init];
_swipeShape.name = swipeShapeName;
_swipeShape.size = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
_swipeShape.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
_swipeShape.zPosition = 10;
_swipeShape.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_swipeShape.size];
_swipeShape.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
_swipeShape.physicsBody.friction = 0.2;
_swipeShape.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.1;
_swipeShape.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0.0;
_swipeShape.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
_swipeShape.physicsBody.mass = .1;
_swipeShape.color = _colorArray[self.randomInt];
_swipeShape.colorBlendFactor = 1;
_swipeShape.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2);
_swipeShape.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = colorCategoryArray[r] | swipeShapeCategory;
_swipeShape.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = colorCategoryArray[r] | goalCategory | coinCategory;
_swipeShape.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = bumperCategory;
_swipeShape.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
[_worldLayer addChild:_swipeShape];

CGFloat ballSpeed = self.gameLevel / 2;

if (ballSpeed > 0) {
    ballSpeed = 15;
}

const CGFloat angle = DegreesToRadians(RandomFloat() * 360);
const CGVector velocity = CGVectorMake(cos(angle)*ballSpeed, sin(angle)*ballSpeed);
[_swipeShape.physicsBody applyImpulse:velocity atPoint:CGPointMake(0, 30)];

  }
```

Comment: What happens if you use mass 100 or 1000 instead of 10? What if you make both bodies the same shape (ie both circles)? AFAIK mass depends on the size of the shape (internally Box2D calculates with density), and perhaps the shape itself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up increasing the mass as suggested for the ball. I also added the ballCategory to the collision bit mask for the swipeShape. The combination did it, so thanks!